# Declare or set results(multiple) of a query as a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

Trying to set a variable from the result(s) of a SELECT statement but since the statement returns multiple results it will not let me assign it.

**Background** When I connect to the database any query I run would be on the `MASTER` database. I need to query the database names from `sys.databases` where the database name ends with '_UK' to run my queries on THOSE databases.

My approach was to set the variable @my_dn_name

```
DECLARE @my_db_name AS VARCHAR(100) = (
    SELECT name
    FROM sys.databases
    WHERE name like '%_UK'
)
```

I would then be able to use `USE @my_db_name` to run my query

Problem is on some host, this select statement returns multiple results thus won't assign the variable. Can someone think of a better approach?

Comment: You need to explain how you would handle multiple results, i.e. what is the desired behaviour?

Comment: And I think you will find that the `USE` statement doesn't take a variable anyway.

Comment: You should be using the `sysname` datatype for your table name (as per the answer below), your current variable isn't large enough to contain the largest possible database name.

Answer (score 1):

You can't store multiple values in a scalar variable. While you could use a table variable, that won't help you because `USE` cannot be parameterized.

Instead you need to use a cursor to execute `EachDatabase.sys.sp_executesql` with your query.

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
-- your queries here
-- SELECT whatever
';

DECLARE @dbname sysname, @proc nvarchar(1000), @crsr CURSOR;

SET @crsr = CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY STATIC READ_ONLY FOR
    SELECT name
    FROM sys.databases
    WHERE name like '%_UK';

OPEN @crsr;

WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM @crsr INTO @dbname;
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
        RETURN;

    SET @proc = @dbname + '.sys.sp_executesql';
    EXEC @proc @sql;  -- optionally add parameters
END;
```

Answer (score -1):

Going from memory does this help?

```sql
DECLARE @my_db_name AS NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @my_db_name = ''

SELECT @my_db_name + ',' + ISNULL(name, 'Unknown')
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name like '%_UK'

PRINT @my_db_name
```

Comment: Hi Kane,
Please explain what this does, how it does it, and how it answers the question.  Code only answers are discouraged.